# C# deserialize json into dictionary and reverse KV

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, serialization

I am trying to deserialize json and reverse the key/value with the least amount of complexity. I have an input json that looks like:

```
{
    "1":"apple",
    "2":"banana",
    "3":"orange",
    "4":"grape"
}
```

And want to serialize this into a `Dictionary<string,string>`, but reverse the dictionary so the fruit is the `key` and the integers are the `value`. Any way to achieve that with `Newtonsoft.Json`?

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,string>>(json);
// obj.Keys = { "1", "2", "3" }, but I want them to be { "apple", "banana", ... }
```

Comment: *"with the least amount of complexity"* Code complexity? Time complexity? Memory complexity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The least complex way would be to just create another dictionary from the one you've deserialised:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,string>>(json)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Value, x => x.Key);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
            Dictionary<string, string> temp = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            Parallel.ForEach(obj, (item)=> {
                temp.Add(item.Value, item.Key);
            });
```

This is the simplified way you can achieve this .

Comment: `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is not thread-safe. You should not be modifying one from multiple threads, such as from `Parallel.ForEach`.

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach` is a simplified way?  Really?

Comment: Yeah . It is a simplified way and also has will take less time in case of large data .